# Android MPAndroidChart xasis values showing more than 1

Tags: java, android, plot, graph, mpandroidchart

I am using android java MPAndroidChart Library.
As you can see from photo, value of x axis showing more than one. I just want to show tuesday one time. How can I do it
[image of chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pspWk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution
lets say your name of the list is myArray and answer is

```
barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(myArray.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a count of label by force. This will result into one label only on your axis.
For example:

```
xAxis.setLabelCount(1, true)
```

From the documentation:

```
 /**
     * sets the number of label entries for the y-axis max = 25, min = 2, default: 6, be aware
     * that this number is not
     * fixed (if force == false) and can only be approximated.
     *
     * @param count the number of y-axis labels that should be displayed
     * @param force if enabled, the set label count will be forced, meaning that the exact
     *              specified count of labels will
     *              be drawn and evenly distributed alongside the axis - this might cause labels
     *              to have uneven values
     */
    public void setLabelCount(int count, boolean force) {

        setLabelCount(count);
        mForceLabels = force;
    }
```

The other thing you can try is working more with granularity.
Like so:

```
axisLeft.granularity = 3F
```

From the docs:

```
 /**
     * Set a minimum interval for the axis when zooming in. The axis is not allowed to go below
     * that limit. This can be used to avoid label duplicating when zooming in.
     *
     * @param granularity
     */
    public void setGranularity(float granularity) {
        mGranularity = granularity;
        // set this to true if it was disabled, as it makes no sense to call this method with granularity disabled
        mGranularityEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for yor answer but these are not working also first code makes invisible.